# How can I align another button with right navigation item (UIBarButtonItem)?

Tags: ios, swift

I am setting my right navigation item to `UIBarButtonSystemItem.edit`. In the view that I am adding underneath a nav bar (in `viewDidLoad`) I have a button that I would like to align with the right navigation item.

I don't really know how to do it given that I can't add any constraints to `UIBarButtonItem` types.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably have to set programmatically. `navigationItem.rightNavigationItems` which takes array of `BarButtonItems`